Setting thresholds for disk I/O metrics like wr_sec/s or rd_sec/s from sar command
We have a Red Hat Kafka servers, and the disk utilization on the Kafka disk is very high almost 100%.
What we observe from the sar command is that the values of rd_sec/s and wr_sec/s are high.
The question is: how can we determine if these values exceed the threshold?
The Kafka disk is a RAID 10 disk with a size of 10 TB.
So, how can we identify the threshold for read and write operations to the disk?
For example, can we say that values greater than 1,000,000 rd_sec/s and wr_sec/s are considered high?
sar -d -p | grep sda

04:05:24 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
04:05:41 PM       sda    496.00  82624.00      0.00    166.58     49.43     93.84      2.02    100.10
04:05:42 PM       sda   3686.00  90528.00 2877784.00    805.29     46.88     14.00      0.27    100.00
04:05:43 PM       sda    644.00 106208.00  10576.00    181.34     49.16     71.65      1.55    100.10
04:05:44 PM       sda    493.00  81016.00    328.00    165.00     47.27     89.59      2.03    100.00
04:05:45 PM       sda   1515.00 257952.00   2944.00    172.21     29.20     26.59      0.66    100.00
04:05:46 PM       sda   2202.00 366560.00      0.00    166.47     18.77      8.12      0.45    100.00
04:05:47 PM       sda   4262.00 187016.00 2784160.00    697.13     41.59      7.48      0.23    100.10
04:05:48 PM       sda    239.00  38144.00      0.00    159.60     49.27    163.82      4.18    100.00
04:05:49 PM       sda    468.00  77872.00    968.00    168.46     47.61    142.10      2.14    100.00
04:05:50 PM       sda   2185.00 368568.00      0.00    168.68     19.22      9.47      0.46    100.00
04:05:51 PM       sda   2273.00 369520.00      0.00    162.57     20.25      8.96      0.44    100.00
04:05:52 PM       sda   2331.00 260432.00 698720.00    411.48     34.09     11.69      0.43    100.00
04:05:53 PM       sda   1492.00 247320.00      0.00    165.76     35.85     28.13      0.67    100.00
04:05:54 PM       sda   2375.00 392224.00    840.00    165.50     22.43      9.50      0.42    100.00
04:05:55 PM       sda   2686.00 439160.00      0.00    163.50     22.87      8.82      0.38    102.00

